# How I use onChange event on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onchange

I want to change the state by using `onChange` event in React. It can be done by `onClick` event but I need it when a user selects a file while updating property data. If user selects cancel, no data would be stored, but due to `onClick`, it stores the data in state.

This is when I use `onClick`:

```html
<button
  type="button"
  className="rounded-full bg-green-400"
  onClick={() => {
    onImageUpdate(index),
    image.data_url === undefined
      ? setDeletedImage([...deletedImage, image.image])
      : null
  }}
>
  <img
    className='p-2 w-8 h-8'
    src={"/images/edit.svg"}
  />
</button>
```

I was expecting like this:

```html
<button
  type="button"
  className="rounded-full bg-green-400"
  onChange={() => {
    image.data_url === undefined
      ? setDeletedImage([...deletedImage, image.image])
      : null
  }}
  onClick={() => { onImageUpdate(index) }}
>
  <img
    className='p-2 w-8 h-8'
    src={"/images/edit.svg"}
  />
</button>
```

Comment: I don't think that `onChange` would be appropriate here - you're not changing the button, you're clicking it. What if you were to change the element type? For example, make it an `input type="file" accepts="*/*"` (or whatever format you want). Then you could implement the `onChange`.

Comment: You're right. But in my use case button is working perfectly cause I'm using a library React-Images-Uploading. Can you suggest me a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You should use 2 components: 1 file input and 1 button. When the file input changes (use `onChange` listener), you set some state. Then when the button is clicked (use `onClick` listener), you take what's in the state and do some action with it. You could also add yet another button for "cancel" that clears the state.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, which will keep track of the selected file in React state.

```js
import React from 'react';

// create a component
const MyComponent = () => {
    // use a state variable to hold information about what file was selected
    // for example, you could store the filename or a File object
    const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState(/* ... */);

    // return an input and some buttons together
    return (
        <>
            <input
                type='file'
                onChange={(event) => {
                    // set the state based on what file the user chose
                    setMyState(/* ... */)
                }}
            />
            <button
                type='button'
                onClick={() => {
                    // do something with myState
                }}
            >
                Submit
            </button>
            <button
                type='button'
                onClick={() => {
                    // clear the state back to null or something
                    setMyState(/* ... */)
                }}
            >
                Cancel
            </button>
        </>
    );
};
```